# $\widetilde{R}=\bigcap_{\mathsf{ht}(\mathfrak p)=1}R_\mathfrak p$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, normalization

As we know every normal Noetherian domain $R$ can be written as $$R=\bigcap_{\mathsf{ht}(\mathfrak p)=1}R_\mathfrak p.$$ I'm asking myself the following question:

**Question:** If the normalization of $\widetilde{R}$ is given by $$\widetilde{R}=\bigcap_{\mathsf{ht}(\mathfrak p)=1}R_\mathfrak p,$$ then is $R$ normal?

Every reference or counterexample is well accepted.

Comment: What precisely are you asking?  For "most" Noetherian integral domains $R$ that are regular in codimension $1$, the normalization $\widetilde{R}$ equals the intersection over all height $1$ primes of $R_\mathfrak{p}$ (perhaps there are issues in the non-excellent case since $\widetilde{R}$ need not be finite over $R$).  For example, for a field $k$ of characteristic $\neq 2$, the $k$-subalgebra $R$ of $k[x,y]$ generated by $x,xy,y^2-1,y^3-y$ gives one example.

Comment: Is there anything which is not clear in my question?

Comment: You have not listed any hypotheses on $R$ except for the displayed equation.  Are you assuming that $R$ is an integral domain?  Are you assuming that $R$ is Noetherian?  Are you assuming that the normalization of $R$ is a finite extension of $R$?  None of this is made clear.  At any rate, as my comment above explains, the result fails even if you add all of these hypotheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just posting my comments as an answer.  First, in the positive direction, for a Noetherian, integral domain $R$ with fraction field $K$, if $R$ satisfies Serre's condition $S_2$, then the natural inclusion of subrings of $K$, $$R\to \bigcap_{\text{ht}(\mathfrak{p}) = 1} R_{\mathfrak{p}}, $$ is an isomorphism.  Thus, for such a ring, $R$ is normal if and only if the normalization $\widetilde{R}$ equals the intersection above as an $R$-subalgebra of $K$.

However, there are many examples of non-normal, Noetherian, integral domains that fail Serre's condition $S_2$, for which $\widetilde{R}$ equals the intersection.  For instance, for every field $k$ of characteristic different from $2$, the following $k$-subalgebra $R$ of the polynomial ring $k[x,y]$ is a non-normal, Noetherian, integral domain that fails Serre's condition $S_2$, and for which the normalization $\widetilde{R}$ equals the intersection above, $$R = k[x,xy,y^2-1,y^3-y]\subset k[x,y].$$